# Serious slow performance when inserting a column in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

In Excel 2007 there was no issue but when I hit the below line in Excel 2016, it now takes over a minute each time. There are only 300 rows in the column. All I want to do is cut a column and paste it next to another column.

```
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

Sample code is as follows, but I have 30 odd of these so it is taking half an hour.

```
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) should speed it up. Test if it takes the same/similar amount of time if you do it manually with ctrl+x/ctrl+v. If yes then it is no programming issue, but an issue with your worksheet and the data it contains.

Comment: Are you sure that you only have 300 rows? This is executed in no time if the sheet is small, but takes forever if a cell  far down/right is filled (maybe accidently).

Comment: Hi, I have tried this and still an issue on line                                    
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, I even tried using a named range to only select the 300 rows in the column with data and still takes ages

Comment: Have you tried any other methods, like insert the column, then cut and paste it, but just the data.  Also, maybe worth as @FunThomas says, checking what data you have.  Maybe try calculation off for this operation to?

Comment: I ask again: How long does it take if you do it manually with ctrl+x/ctrl+v?

Comment: Could you post the whole code. If it is taking forever, you might have the code in an Event and it should be written differently.

Comment: Yes it takes the same amount of time copying and pasting manually.

Comment: Press Control-Shift - End  - this will take you to the bottom right of the occupied area of the spread sheet. Is that actually row 300?

Comment: Yes it takes the same amount of time copying and pasting manually. Actually I tried just copying one call and pasting and it still took a while. The data in the cell is just 'ID" ! I'm not able to paste full code due to security where I work.

Comment: Nope definitely only 300 rows of data after pressing CTRL+SHIFT+END

Comment: • Do you have any events in VBA if so please show their code. • Did you try to copy paste the data into a completely new workbook and test it their if you got the same issues?

Comment: Yes I copied all the sheets and macros to a new workbook and still the same performance issues. The file itself is only 10MB so not a massive workbook by any means. No events in VBA either. I think it is to do with the fact there is fair bit of data in multiple sheets?

Comment: Well it can can happen if there are many formulas in your sheet especially if they are volatile they can cause a heavy load on re-calculation. Is it slow too if you set calculation to manual before you cut/paste?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have formulas and maybe even external references? Then please try this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateRemoteReferences = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

ActiveSheet.Columns("E:E").Cut
ActiveSheet.Columns("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksAlways
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateRemoteReferences = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

' If it's faster, then uncomment following line additionally
' Application.CalculateFull
```

Comment: Thanks very much but unfortunately this did not work. I don;t have any formulas or external references. If I ever find a solution I will update this post

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with an Excel xlsx file generated by a Payroll system. Not sure what is causing the slowness on column insert. Inserting a column into a 88,000 row file takes about 25 seconds.

I discovered that if I copy the entire worksheet to a new sheet as values and number formats, the insert column step will run almost instantly. The copy entire worksheet portion takes just 3 seconds! There are no formulas in the file nor conditional formatting.

This is the logic I used:

```
' Copy source worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells
rng.Copy ' note that wks.Cells.Copy is very slow

' add new worksheet
Dim newWks As Worksheet
Set newWks = Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)
newWks.Name = "Values Only"

' paste values and number format into new worksheet
newWks.Range("A1").Select
' xlPasteValues is fast too
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
' if I also include a xlPasteFormats then the insert column will become very slow once again
'  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


' now the column insert is blazingly fast!
newWks.Columns(14).Insert
newWks.Cells(1, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
' etc.
```